# Conversion of CRC function from C to C# yields wrong values

Tags: c#, c

I'm trying to convert a couple of simple CRC calculating functions from `C` to `C#`, but I seem to be getting incorrect results.

The `C` functions are:

```
#define CRC32_POLYNOMIAL 0xEDB88320 
unsigned long CRC32Value(int i) 
{ 
  int j; 
  unsigned long ulCRC; 
  ulCRC = i; 
  for (j=8;j>0;j--) 
  { 
       if (ulCRC & 1) 
          ulCRC = (ulCRC >> 1)^CRC32_POLYNOMIAL; 
       else 
          ulCRC >>= 1; 
  } 
  return ulCRC; 
} 

unsigned long CalculateBlockCRC32(  
       unsigned long ulCount, 
       unsigned char *ucBuffer) 
{ 
  unsigned long ulTemp1; 
  unsigned long ulTemp2; unsigned long ulCRC = 0; 
  while (ulCount-- != 0) 
  { 
    ulTemp1 = (ulCRC >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFFL; 
    ulTemp2 = CRC32Value(((int)ulCRC^*ucBuffer++)&0xff); 
    ulCRC = ulTemp1^ulTemp2; 
  } 
  return(ulCRC); 
}
```

These are well defined, they are taken from a user manual. My C# versions of these functions are:

```
    private ulong CRC32POLYNOMIAL = 0xEDB88320L;

    private ulong CRC32Value(int i)
    {

        int j;
        ulong ulCRC = (ulong)i;
        for (j = 8; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (ulCRC % 2 == 1)
            {
                ulCRC = (ulCRC >> 1) ^ CRC32POLYNOMIAL;
            }
            else
            {
                ulCRC >>= 1;
            }
        }

        return ulCRC;
    }

    private ulong CalculateBlockCRC32(ulong ulCount, byte[] ucBuffer)
    {
        ulong ulTemp1;
        ulong ulTemp2;
        ulong ulCRC=0;
        int bufind=0;

        while (ulCount-- != 0)
        {
            ulTemp1 = (ulCRC >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFFL;
            ulTemp2 = CRC32Value(((int)ulCRC ^ ucBuffer[bufind]) & 0xFF);
            ulCRC = ulTemp1 ^ ulTemp2;
            bufind++;
        }
        return ulCRC;
    }
```

As I mentioned, there are discrepancies between the `C` version and the `C#` version. One possible source is my understanding of the `C` expression `ulCRC & 1` which I believe will only be true for odd numbers.

I call the `C#` function like this:

```
string contents = "some data";
byte[] toBeHexed = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents);
ulong calculatedCRC = this.CalculateBlockCRC32((ulong)toBeHexed.Length, toBeHexed);
```

And the `C` function is called like this:

```
char *Buff="some data"; 
unsigned long iLen = strlen(Buff); 
unsigned long CRC = CalculateBlockCRC32(iLen, (unsigned char*) Buff);
```

I believe that I am calling the functions with the same data in each language, is that correct? If anyone could shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

Comment: `unsigned long` in C is `uint` in C# (well actually with `modopt(long) uint`). `ulong` in C# is `unsigned long long` in C.

Comment: If you know some places where there is a discrepancy can you not just debug the two programs to find where they behave differently? ie have lots of unit tests and use them to track down your bugs.

Comment: Also I think this might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (though I may be wrong, I don't frequent there). Stack Overflow is more about helping with specific problems than just "my program doesn't do what I expect".

Comment: @Chris: CR *only* reviews working code, don't redirect people there when their question is offtopic.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Cool. I'll remember that for the future.

Answer (score 1):

As it has been already pointed by @Adriano Repetti you should use [`UInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32(v=vs.110).aspx) datatype in place of the [`ulong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx) type(it is 64 bit unsigned [`UInt64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uint32(v=vs.110).aspx), whereas in [VC++ `unsigned long`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) is only 32 bit unsigned type)

```
    private UInt32 CRC32POLYNOMIAL = 0xEDB88320;

    private UInt32 CRC32Value(int i)
    {

        int j;
        UInt32 ulCRC = (UInt32)i;
        for (j = 8; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (ulCRC % 2 == 1)
            {
                ulCRC = (ulCRC >> 1) ^ CRC32POLYNOMIAL;
            }
            else
            {
                ulCRC >>= 1;
            }
        }

        return ulCRC;
    }

    private UInt32 CalculateBlockCRC32(UInt32 ulCount, byte[] ucBuffer)
    {
        UInt32 ulTemp1;
        UInt32 ulTemp2;
        UInt32 ulCRC = 0;
        int bufind = 0;

        while (ulCount-- != 0)
        {
            ulTemp1 = (ulCRC >> 8) & 0x00FFFFFF;
            ulTemp2 = CRC32Value(((int)ulCRC ^ ucBuffer[bufind]) & 0xFF);
            ulCRC = ulTemp1 ^ ulTemp2;
            bufind++;
        }
        return ulCRC;
    }

    string contents = "12";
    byte[] toBeHexed = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(contents);
    UInt32 calculatedCRC = CalculateBlockCRC32((UInt32)toBeHexed.Length, toBeHexed);
```

Usually in C# it doesn't matter whether you use C# data type name(recommended by Microsoft) or ECMA type name. But in this and similar cases with bit level manipulation it can greatly clarify the intent and prevent mistakes.

In C it is always a good idea to use typedefs from [stdint.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdint/). They make the same job, as ECMA types in C# - clarify the intent, and also guarantee the length and sign of used datatypes(C compilers may use different lengths for the same types, because standard doesn't specify exact sizes):

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define CRC32_POLYNOMIAL ((uint32_t)0xEDB88320)
uint32_t CRC32Value(uint32_t i) 
{ 
  uint32_t j; 
  uint32_t ulCRC; 
  ulCRC = i; 

  for (j = 8; j > 0; j--) 
  { 
       if (ulCRC & 1) 
          ulCRC = (ulCRC >> 1) ^ CRC32_POLYNOMIAL; 
       else 
          ulCRC >>= 1; 
  } 
  return ulCRC; 
} 

uint32_t CalculateBlockCRC32(  
       size_t ulCount, 
       uint8_t *ucBuffer) 
{ 
  uint32_t ulTemp1; 
  uint32_t ulTemp2; 
  uint32_t ulCRC = 0;

  while (ulCount-- != 0) 
  { 
    ulTemp1 = (ulCRC >> 8) & ((uint32_t)0x00FFFFFF); 
    ulTemp2 = CRC32Value((ulCRC^*ucBuffer++)&0xff); 
    ulCRC = ulTemp1^ulTemp2; 
  } 

  return(ulCRC); 
}

char *Buff = "12"; 
size_t iLen = strlen(Buff); 
uint32_t CRC = CalculateBlockCRC32(iLen, (uint8_t *) Buff);
printf("%u", CRC);
```